# How do you hide the status bar on the splash/launch screen (titanium)

Tags: titanium-mobile

```
 <fullscreen>true</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>true</navbar-hidden>
```

I have tried this (in the tiapp.xml) settings, but it doesn't work.

Any idea how to resolve this problem.

Comment: see if this helps: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/8781/hide-statusbar-on-splash-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Titanium has changed things:

```
            <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
            <true/>
```

Set that to true in your tiapp settings